# Stealth scan or -PS

Tags: nmap, host-discovery

I want to find out how `-PS` works for service discovery very well when there are the stealth scan options such as `-sS`, available in nmap.

I am currently testing nmap.scanme.org and I know there is a full TCP handshake on some ports so a stealth scan is advised but `-PS` seems to give me just what I am looking for, service name on the port.

> "The -P* options (which select ping types) can be combined. You can
> increase your odds of penetrating strict firewalls by sending many
> probe types using different TCP ports/flags and ICMP codes."

This is what caught my attention from the man page of *nmap*. I still don't see how it is possible for `-PS` to perform this fast and indeed successful when you also take into consideration the `-sS` option. ICMP codes may be the culprit but I am not sure to be honest.

Comment: Have you read the man pages? What bit didn't you understand?

Comment: @RoryAlsop A three way handshake and closing of the connection follows when you look for a port's availability. Here, -PS usage does seem to be successful when -sS is logically needed in order to avoid the issue in my first sentence here. I have read the --help only, sorry. I will be checking further.